# jquery camelcase implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, unicode

I was looking at the jquery source and notice that camelcase is:

```
camelCase: function( string ) {
    return string.replace( rmsPrefix, "ms-" ).replace( rdashAlpha, fcamelCase );
}

// where:
rmsPrefix = /^-ms-/,
rdashAlpha = /-([\da-z])/gi,
fcamelCase = function( all, letter ) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
}
```

My question is: why does `rdashAlpha` also look for digits, is there a point calling a touppercase on a digit? is there some unicode chars that this can change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'll notice, the function also removes hyphens. No, it's not necessary to uppercase a number or an uppercase letter, but the function is designed to replace the entire match (e.g., "-2" or "-w" or "-W") with just the first character.

Calling `.toUpperCase()` on everything is certainly easier, cleaner, and probably faster than *determining whether or not* to call it.